# Вывести несколько графиков на одной фигуре

Tags: python, matplotlib

Как вывести множество линий на один график?

```
plt.plot([[0,1,2,3,2,1,2,3],[7,2,1],[3,6,4,2,1]])
plt.show()
```

Этот код не работает из-за разной длины

Речь именно о том, как вывести такой список в один график.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/plot-multiple-lines-in-matplotlib/

циклы: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [[0,1,2,3,2,1,2,3],[7,2,1],[3,6,4,2,1]]

for value in values:
   plt.plot(value)

plt.show()
```

Comment: используйте цикл

Comment: непонятно что значит использовать цикл :)

Comment: обновил ответ..